Is it possible to force `git add -p` to use a different diff algorithm without changing the repository config?
If I do the following:
git config diff.algorithm patience
git add -p

then git add -p forms its diffs using the patience algorithm.  Is there any way to force git add -p to use patience as a one-off without setting that option for the repository?  (Of course I can just do the above and git unset diff.algorithm, but that seems inelegant.)

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-add%5D+algorithm
